# Create light overlay from heavy shapefile to use in web app

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, overlay

A question about soundness of principle as much as method, as I am very new to the subject.

Having to serve over web the polygons in way too large a shapefile (200Mb), I am wondering: could I, with some tool, convert all the data in the shapefile into a single transparent image (png I suppose, covering about 20,000km2) to then use as an easy to load overlay in google maps ?

Edit:
I seem to understand Geoserver and Mapserver would create and serve selected, appropriate tiles of the resulting image on demand.
Not lastly because we don't have a server to run Geoserver at hand, and since the data is static, I was thinking more of an actual image file. Does it make sense ?

Comment: its called a WMS and is the usual procedure, look at GeoServer or MapServer to get started.

Comment: Am thinking, convert it to geojson and load and style it, overlay it to googlemaps.

Comment: @saviour123 There are about 16,000 polygons.

Comment: okay, for server, You could get aws or gce for free for start and run geoserver on it. You could merge all the polygons into one and then convert it to raster. 
//merge http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000055000000.htm
//convert to raster. You can look at this options: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm //you can check to see if its what you want.

Comment: use geoserver to create a tiled WMS, which is basically a pre-rendered set of images of the styled shapefile - clients only download the picture from the server, rather than the data itself.

Comment: Does this look, to savvier eyes than mine, like what I'm looking to get ?   https://gist.github.com/ianfieldhouse/2284557   - and then I'm picturing it anchored and scaled along with the zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself after further research and practical experience.

What I propose in the question (making one giant png) is, alas, daft.
I attempted the task in QGis, and the result is a massive png (100mb+) with a ridiculously low detail, no matter the options selected.

Geoserver it is.